# SQL query for most recent orders

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, oracle

I have the following two tables:

Users [Table]

```
UserID [PK] (Integer)
FirstName (VarChar)
LastName (VarChar)
EmailAddress (VarChar)
RegistrationDate (DateTime)
```

Orders [Table]

```
OrderId [PK] (Integer)
UserId [FK] (Integer)
OrderDate (DateTime)
OrderFulfilled (Boolean)
```

I need to write a query to show the 100 most recent orders submitted prior to the current day that have not had their orders fulfilled yet. I need to Include their order date, their order id, their email address, and their registration date.

Could someone help me with this?

Thanks

Comment: Did you try anything to achieve that? If yes then please share what you tried and show  your expected output based on some sample input. `oracle, mysql, sql-server`?

Comment: oracle, sql-server and mysql have specific non sql standard functions and syntax. What is your exact environment?

Comment: Don't tag products not involved! You won't find an answer that runs on Oracle, MySQL and SQL Server...

Comment: I had an idea about using the join but could not figure out how to write it. I am looking for some generic sql query irrespective of the environment since the basics are the same, I think. My goal is just to get an idea of writing the query whether it is Oracle, SQL or MySQL. Both the answers below should work for me. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This query will work properly for you -

```
SELECT OrderId, OrderDate, EmailAddress, RegistrationDate
FROM Orders as o
INNER JOIN Users as u
ON o.UserID = u.UserID
WHERE OrderDate < CURDATE()
AND OrderFulfilled = 0
ORDER BY OrderDate DESC
LIMIT 0,100
```

Comment: Which dbms is this for?

Comment: it is using for "MySql"

Comment: MySQL is fine. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Use the SELECT TOP statement in an MS SQL Server environment:

```
SELECT TOP 100 *
FROM Orders o
INNER JOIN Users u
ON o.UserID = u.UserID
WHERE OrderDate < CAST(SYSDATETIME() AS DATE)
AND OrderFulfilled = 0
ORDER BY OrderDate DESC
```

For oracle use:

```
ROWNUM <= 100
```

For mySql use:

```
LIMIT 100
```

Comment: Which dbms is this for?

Comment: Read it again. Example is for SQL-Server, instead of the TOP 100 use ROWNUM <= 100 below the ORDER BY for Oracle. For mySql remove the TOP 100 and use LIMIT 100 instead. So it works for all DBMS in the tags.